# How can I automate the computation of abstract derivatives using sympy in Python?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

For my research, I am having to compute abstract derivatives which I was thinking of automating via code. The derivatives are in [image: derivatives], that act on themselves and on [image: u_m], in the following way:

1. [image: derivative1]
2. [image: derivative2],

where [image: a] is a smooth function of [image: u]. These are then extended via linearity, chain rule, and product rule to a larger space. So, for example, for [image: q], one would have:

1. [image: vq]
2. [image: v1q]

and for any smooth function [image: a] of [image: u],

[image: f']

I have tried to use the python package [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html). My initial code looks like:

```
from sympy import symbols, Function, KroneckerDelta

a = Function('a')
j = symbols('j', integer=True)
m = symbols('m', integer=True)
n = symbols('n', integer=True)
q = symbols('q')
u = Function('u')(j)
v = Function('v')(m,n)

def symbolic_derivative(k, l, u1, v1):
    du = KroneckerDelta(k, 0) * KroneckerDelta(l, u1.args[0]) * 1/q
    dv = KroneckerDelta(k, 0) * KroneckerDelta(l, 0) * (a(u).diff(u) * v1.subs([(v1.args[0],v1.args[0]+1),(v1.args[1],v1.args[1])]))/q + KroneckerDelta(k,v1.args[0]) * KroneckerDelta(l,v1.args[1])
    return du,dv
#Checking an example case
u = u.subs(j,1)
v = v.subs([(m,3),(n,2)])
print(symbolic_derivative(0,0,u,v))
```

which gives the correct base derivatives, but I am at a loss on how to extend it? Ideally it should be able to compute things like [image: derivative1]. How should I proceed?

Comment: Given that this is a pretty specialized question, you might try a Sympy-specific forum, if you don't get a workable response here.